Changing shortcuts / key bindings via the interface - v14.0
I understand this has been asked in the past, but I'm not sure whether / to what extent the answers pertain to version 14.0. So:

Is there a way to introduce/change key bindings via the interface, i.e., without editing the KeyEventTranslations.tr?
If the answer to 1. is negative, is there a step-by-step guide on how to edit that file?

Example: I would like a shortcut to change the cell style to Item, similar to how Alt+1 changes the cell style to Title.

If you are using a mac, it is pretty easy to add a keyboard shortcut using system settings. Also, are you aware that starting a new cell with an asterisk will create an "Item" cell?

I wasn't aware, that basically solves the particular problem, thank you!
The general question still stands though (I'm on a PC).
